# create isolated stacks with terraform as with the serverless framework on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am developing a serverless data pipeline on AWS. Compared to the [Serverless framework](https://serverless.com/), [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) has better support for services like Glue.

The good thing about Serverless is that you can define the `--stage` argument when deploying. This allows creating an isolated stack on AWS. When developing new features on our data pipeline I can deploy my state of the code like

```
serverless deploy --stage my-new-feature
```

this allows me to do an isolated integration test on the AWS account I share with my colleagues. Is this possible using Terraform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform manages resources by way of state.

If a resource already exists in the state file and Terraform doesn't detect any drift between the configuration, the state and any differences in the provider (eg something was changed in the AWS console or by another tool) then it will show that there are no changes. If it does detect some form of drift then a `plan` will show you what changes it needs to make to push the existing state of things in the provider to what is defined in the Terraform code.

### Separating state between different environments

If you want to have multiple environments or even other resources that are separate from each other and not managed by the same Terraform action (such as a `plan`, `apply` or `destroy`) then you want to separate these into different state files.

One way to do this is to separate your Terraform code by environment and use a state file matching the directory structure of your code base. A simple example might look something like this:

```
terraform/
├── production
│   ├── main.tf -> ../stacks/main.tf
│   └── terraform.tfvars
├── stacks
│   └── main.tf
└── staging
    ├── main.tf -> ../stacks/main.tf
    └── terraform.tfvars
```

#### stacks/main.tf

```
variable "environment" {}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "foo" {
  function_name = "foo-${var.environment}"
  # ...
}
```

#### production/terraform.tfvars

```
environment = "production"
```

#### staging/terraform.tfvars

```
environment = "staging"
```

This uses symlinks so that staging and production are kept in line in code with the only changes being introduced by the `terraform.tfvars` file. In this case it changes the Lambda function's name to include the environment.

This is what I generally recommend for static environments as it's much clearer from looking at the code/directory structure which environments exist.

### Dynamic environments

However, if you have more dynamic environments, such as per feature branch, then it's not going to work to hard code the environment name directly in your `terraform.tfvars` file.

In this case I would recommend something like this:

```
terraform/
├── production
│   ├── main.tf -> ../stacks/main.tf
│   └── terraform.tfvars
├── review
│   ├── main.tf -> ../stacks/main.tf
│   └── terraform.tfvars
├── stacks
│   └── main.tf
└── staging
    ├── main.tf -> ../stacks/main.tf
    └── terraform.tfvars
```

This works the same way but I would omit the `environment` variable from the `review` structure so that it's set interactively or via CI environment variables (eg `export TF_VAR_environment=${TRAVIS_BRANCH}` when running in Travis CI, adapt this to support whatever CI system you use).

### Keeping state separate between review environments on different branches

This only gets you half way though because when another person tries to use this with another branch then they will see that Terraform wants to destroy/update any resources that are already created by running Terraform if you were just using the default [workspace](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html).

Workspaces provide an option for separating state in a more dynamic way and also allows you to [interpolate the workspace name into Terraform code](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html#current-workspace-interpolation):

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  tags {
    Name = "web - ${terraform.workspace}"
  }

  # ... other arguments
}
```

Instead the review environments will need to create or use a dynamic workspace that is scoped for that branch only. You can do this by running the following [command](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/workspace/new.html):

```
terraform workspace new [NAME]
```

If the workspace already exists then you should instead use the following [command](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/workspace/select.html):

```
terraform workspace select [NAME]
```

In CI you can use the same environment variables as before to automatically use the branch name as your workspace name.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have a look at workspace? https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html

Comment: This would be a better answer if it was expanded to provide examples or to explain more about what workspaces help with. Right now it's pretty much a link only answer and if that link breaks then this answer isn't helpful.